# Is "any" also used with plurals?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, determiners

I found on a research paper the following statement:

> Is any particular images satisfying the requirements ?

I thought *any* can only be used with singular terms. So I was surprised when I've seen "images" rather than "image".

Am I correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would take that to be a typo. The verb should agree with the noun:

> - **Is** any particular **image** satisfying the requirements?
> - **Are** any particular **images** satisfying the requirements?

*Any* can be safely used in both cases. Have a look at these example sentences from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/any):

> - Choose any items you want. [*items* — plural]
> - Any person may apply. [*person* — singular]
> - I haven't got any money. [*money* — uncountable]

Merriam-Webster defines *any* [as follows](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/any):

> 1. **one or some** indiscriminately of whatever kind [...]
> 2. **one, some, or all** indiscriminately of whatever quantity [...]

Emphasis mine.

Lastly, note psmears' comment that it might be more appropriate to use present simple rather than present continuous in your case (though further context might justify either). I will also add that there should be [no space before the question mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/a-space-before-a-question-or-an-exclamation-mark-can-it-be-correct).

Comment: Note that the sentences here, though correct, are unusual: it's far more common to say *Does any particular image satisfy the requirements?*, which has a slightly different meaning - but without more context it's impossible to know which is appropriate...

Comment: +1: Not bad for an NNS. @psmears, I'm sure @RegDwight is confining his answer to the actual question at hand, not giving supererogatory lessons in writing.

Comment: @Robusto: Yes, I know that RegDwight is well aware of what I'm saying :-p I'm just pointing it out for the benefit of others who might otherwise misinterpret "This is grammatically correct" as "This is what you actually want to say/write" :)

Comment: I was going to add the same comment, @psmears. Definitely worth pointing out given that people come here for Everyday Usage assistance. @Robusto, what is 'NNS', by the way?

Comment: @Karl: NNS = Non-native speaker. I kid @RegDwight because English is his third language, even though his use of it is about 99.999% perfect.

Comment: @Karl and psmears: I've updated the answer accordingly. @Robusto: you misspelled "9.9999% perfect".

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, @Robusto. I was overthinking forum/internet speak. Also, wouldn't have guessed that it was a 3rd language!

Comment: @RegDwight: Just the sort of misperception I expect from the NNS contingent here.

Comment: @psmears and RegDwigнt  Why is it more appropriate to use present simple rather than present continuous in this case? I am puzzled.

Comment: @user239460: Because, in general, whether specific images "satisfy requirements" is either true or false - it doesn't tend to change over time - so we use the present simple as it's a generalisation or habit (cf. "I like cats", or "I go to the beach every day"). Present continous would imply that something special was happening *right now* that wasn't necessarily true at other times (cf "I am going to the beach").

Comment: @psmears  It makes sense, thanks, do you mean that using present continous would imply that the images might not satisfy the requirements at other time?

Comment: @user239460: It's more that present continuous would imply that the images are somehow doing something, right now, to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @psmears  Images themselves can't perform, right? I think I got that now, thanks.

Comment: @user239460: Only in a metaphorical sense - which is why that usage is very unusual :-) No problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Is** *one out of all* particular images satisfying the requirements would exactly be what *any* means.