# Any kind of + plural word

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

I have a question about `any kind of`.

```
Results can be applied to any kinds of drawing or texturing applications
```

In the sentence above, should I use `any kind of applications` or `any kinds of applications`?

I checked the Internet and everyone on the web goes for `any kind of`; however, all the examples include uncountable words. But, in my case, because of referring a computer software, `application` is countable and because of using `any`, it should be plural, I guess.

So, basically, is it always `any kind of` or if the word is countable and plural, can I use `any kinds of`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If they can be applied to any kind of drawing, they can be applied to all the various kinds.

Comment: *very* closely related: [Is “any” also used with plurals?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/is-any-also-used-with-plurals) and [“Any” with countable nouns in questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63618/any-with-countable-nouns-in-questions?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouns related to "any" are correctly singular, when there is the possibility that only one thing might be involved.

- "Any person can do this"
- "He looked for any kind of evidence"
- "Any solution is better than none"
- "This works for any kind of drawing"

Using "all" requires plurals:

- "All people can do this"
- "This works for all kinds of drawing"

The associated noun for words like "kind" should always be singular (though it's not a rule that is widely followed)

Comment: So what makes it a rule?

Answer (score 0):

First, "any kind of" can definitely indicate a **multitude** of kinds:-)

If you really want to be   different, I'd go for:

*Results can be applied to **any variety of** drawing or texturing applications*

"Any kind**s** of" is not considered terribly elegant. Now, you can use it, but ... read again previous sentence.

BTW, at Google Books:

"any kind of applications"
About 680 results

["any variety of applications"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22any%20kind%20of%20applications%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22any%20variety%20of%20applications%22)
About 46 results

"any kinds of applications"
About 19 results

Answer (score 0):

It is alright to use both of these which mean the same thing:

> any kind of application
>
> any kind of applications

Although the first is more common. Google search results isn't a good indicator but anyway:

> "any kind of pet" (226000 results)
>
> "any kind of pets" (103000 results)
>
> "any kinds of pets" (102000 results)
>
> "any kinds of pet" (7430 results, mostly false positives where "pet" is a modifier as in "pet food")

Answer (score 0):

singular: *It's **a** kind of **drawing***   e.g. *sketching*
colloquially: They **are** a kind of drawing

plural: *There* **are** *different* ***kinds*** *of* ***drawings***;
e.g. *sketching, pencil, cartoons, and draughting.*

Interrogative:
(i) **Is** etching **a** kind of drawing?
(ii) **Is** there **any** kind of drawing you prefer?   (Is there any *one* kind of drawing)
(iii) Are computer graphics and animation different **kinds** of **drawings**?
(iv)  Are there any **kinds** of technical **drawings**?

> Results can be applied to different **kinds** of **drawings** or texturing applications
>   Results can be applied to any **kind** of **drawings** or texturing applications
>   Results can be applied to any **kind** of **drawing** or textural application

Any form can be used.