# "Any requirement" or "any requirements"

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of the following expressions is grammatically correct:

> 1. I will let you know if I come across **any requirement**.
> 2. I will let you know if I come across **any requirements**.

Comment: Related: [Is “any” also used with plurals?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/is-any-also-used-with-plurals)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either should be syntactically correct, but if you anticipate that there may only be one requirement (e.g., "The class for your child didn't specify a minimum age, but I will let you know if I come across any requirement.") the singular would be preferred. Whereas if it's open-ended and could be any number of unknown requirements, the plural would be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Both of the following are grammatically correct:

> • I will let you know if I come across any requirement.
>   • I will let you know if I come across any requirements.

(See comment below regarding quotation marks.)

Each has a context in which it makes sense; as Ben notes, singular vs plural is one determiner.  If the sentence is a reply, the form of the question asked is important.   For example:

> • Q: Do you know if it has to be more than 5?  A: I will let you know if I come across any requirement like that.
>   • Q: Do you know if it has to be more than 5 or less than 7?  A: I will let you know if I come across any requirements like that.

*Note regarding quotation marks:*  Every sentence of the following form is grammatical, no matter what letters and spaces you substitute for *XYZ*.  Placing *XYZ* in quotation marks indicates that it is a literal quotation, so it doesn't affect grammaticality of the sentence as a whole.

> I will let you know if I come across "XYZ".