# Capitalization of a word after an ellipsis

Tags: capitalization, ellipses

Should I capitalize the word "don't" in the following sentence?

> Listen... don’t panic.

Comment: Why would you use an ellipsis in the first place?

Comment: It's a script. The narrator wants to make a pause after the word "listen", which is longer than what a comma would signify.

Comment: One interesting side point is that even though I've seen many people use a space after but not before an ellipsis, the way you've done here, there actually seem to be few if any style guides that recommend this spacing, according to the answers to the following questions: [Space before three dots?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91653), [Spaces for Ellipses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115022)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, you do not capitalize the word following the ellipsis. I have only ever seen and used spaces in ellipses in academic writing when omitting text from the middle of a quote. For instance, [from the Wikipedia article for linguistic ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), in the sentence:

> In linguistics, ellipsis (from the Greek: ἔλλειψις, élleipsis,
>   "omission") or elliptical construction refers to the omission, from a
>   clause, of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the
>   context of the remaining elements.

I can use ellipses to remove information and inform the reader of the missing text, as you can see if you compare my new sentence to the original:

> In linguistics, ellipsis . . . refers to the omission . . . of one or
>   more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the
>   remaining elements.

In your case, it sounds like you're writing some form of dialogue. When using an ellipsis in *dialogue*, you are indicating a pause in the sentence. You **do not** use spaces or capitalization surrounding the ellipsis. In the sentence you provided, the correct style is:

> "Listen...don’t panic."

Comment: There is also the sentence or 'sentence'-terminal four-dot ellipsis, as in << Listen.... Don't make a sound. >>

Answer (score 2):

No, not in this case, but capitalization is correct if the word following the ellipsis is part of a new sentence.

Comment: In that case, there should be a full stop after the ellipsis (4 dots altogether).