# Using "to" instead of "and"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, grammatical-number, writing

I read the following sentence in an essay:

> The number of visitors to France is approximately between 8 and 10 million each year.

Can I replace "and" with "to", as follows:

> The number of visitors to France is approximately between 8 to 10 million each year.

Comment: No. _Between_ requires _and_. You could change it to 'approximately 8-10 million' which would be spoken as 'eight to ten million'.

Comment: You can say "there are 8 to 10 million", but you can't say "between 8 to 10".

Comment: There is no need for the word 'approximately' – clearly "8 to 10 million" is an approximate figure. Rephrased: "France has between 8 and 10 million visitors each year."

Comment: No spaces before punctuation: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#:~:text=There%20should%20be%20no%20space%20between%20a%20sentence,be%20preceded%20by%20a%20space%20is%20a%20dash.

Comment: 'From x to y' is synonymous with 'between x and y', which may be the source of confusion here. 'Synonymous' means 'interchangeable _in some cases_ with no/negligible change in meaning/emphasis/...' though, and I'd stick with 'The number of visitors to France each year is between 8 and 10 million' or 'There are 8-10 [_or_ between 8 and 10] million visitors to France each year' here.

Comment: @nnnnnn - What do you mean, you can't say it?  I just said it, and very likely OP can say it as well.

Comment: @HotLicks - The Word Police are on their way.