# Including "to" in a phrase/statement

Tags: grammar

I have a question. Should I say; *The place where I went* or *The place where I went to*?

Comment: are you asking how to start a sentence or how to refer to a place you've been?

Comment: The question is perfectly clear to me. Had I not been injuncted by a higher power, I would have answered as follows. 'The place where I went' is good, grammatically-correct, English, and perfectly comprehensible. If you want to add a 'to' (which personally I wouldn't, as I don't like sentences that end with prepositions) that would also be considered good grammar, except you would need to leave out the the 'where'. You might just about get away with 'The place to where I went' but 'The place to which I went' sounds much better.

Comment: @WS2 I second that. Sure, there were typos in it and such but as a question it is totally fine...

Comment: maybe @KitFox will tell us, why exactly it was clo.. I mean, put on hold

Comment: It was closed because the original question was incomprehensible. As it is now, it is still unclear what the question is. There is no context and no explanation of what is confusing or why there is a choice between these two possibilities.

Comment: Actually this has been asked before, in a number of different ways, and the answer has always stayed the same, so WS2 would only be duplicating previous effort here. See e.g. [the answers to this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/is-where-are-you-going-to-correct).