# “...where it’s at.” - Is that grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I stated to a customer, “They can tell you where it’s at” (regarding the office location of an appointment). The customer then asked if he could correct my grammar, to which I consented. It was an older gentleman; he was simply being talkative, so I didn’t mind. He said, “You do not have to say ‘at.’ You can say, ‘They can tell you where it is.’”

Dictionaries such as [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at) don't have any examples of *at* being used at the end of a sentence like this.

Was my statement grammatically acceptable? If so, why?

Comment: Sadly, I can see this developing into another bunfight. Until we have a body legislating on what is correct in English, there will always be border disputes. And if such a body appears, there will be civil war. If you'd asked 'Do you like the usage?' – well, obviously the customer didn't (but I won't make the obvious remark).

Comment: I think this is essentially the same question as [*Can you grammatically end a sentence with “with”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49353/can-you-grammatically-end-a-sentence-with-with), but I hesitate to cite that in a duplicate closevote, so I'll just say "Matter of Opinion".

Comment: *Where it is* and *Where it's at* does not necessarily mean the same. However, there is no context.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better at [ell.stackexchange.com](http://ell.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Helmar I agree, for me (SAE speaker), "Where are you?" and "Where are you at?" are two different questions, and the use of at could be distinguishing in this case as well.  That would make a good answer to talk about it the distinction

Comment: Correctness/incorrectess aside, "where it's at" is \*generally\* very informal, and should probably not be used in professional or academic settings. This includes using it with customers.

Comment: This is always incorrect unless you're standing in front of *two turntables and a microphone*.

Comment: @Mazura - Nah!  Turntables aren't where it's at anymore.

Comment: "where something is at"  is marked as a typical AmE colloquialism.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, your statement was perfectly grammatical.

Your customer is correct that you don’t *have* to say ‘at’: “where it is” is every bit as acceptable as—and in some circumstances *more* acceptable than—“where it’s at”, but “where it’s at” is not ungrammatical as such.

*Where* is usually (or perhaps I should rather say traditionally) labelled a relative adverb in this usage. It’s not really an adverb in the narrower sense of the verb (it doesn’t directly modify the verb in a clause); it is in many ways more akin to a relative pronoun, especially in that it always has an *antecedent*, whether explicit or not. This antecedent is essentially a prepositional phrase of some kind, with the object of the preposition being the place that functions as the ‘actual’ antecedent; if there is no explicit place in the main clause, we assume a generic antecedent like “place” or something like that.

In other words, you can usually replace *where* in a relative clause with a prepositional phrase: “in which [place]”, “at which [place]”, “to which [place]”, etc. Or, since we’re talking about relative clauses here, “that/what … in/at/to/etc.”. Compare:

> This is the school *where* my kids go // This is the school *that* my kids go *to*.
>   This is the house *where/in which* I live // This is the house *that* I live *in*.
>   That is the college *where/at which* I trained // That is the college *that* I trained *at*.

In all these cases, *where* by itself (without the preposition) carries the meaning of the entire prepositional phrase.

Since we always have the corresponding ‘full’ phrase somewhere in the back of our heads, however, and know that underlyingly we’re talking about ‘going *to* school’, ‘living *in* a house’, and ‘training *at* college’, we sometimes add the preposition anyway. Essentially, the only thing this changes is that *where* then does not stand in for the entire prepositional phrase, but only for the place—it becomes entirely synonymous with *that*.

In some cases, this is actually necessarily if you want to specify whether you’re talking about direction or location. A taxi driver, for instance, might ask you, “Where to?” to ask you where you want him to take you, but he wouldn’t just ask “Where?”, because that might as well be asking you where you are or half a dozen other things.

In most cases, though, adding the preposition is unnecessary—and as with many things in language that are not necessary, some people have interpreted its lack of necessity as evidence that it is in fact *wrong*. Hence, we end up with people making outdated claims that sentences like [“Where are you going to?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/is-where-are-you-going-to-correct) are ‘not grammatically correct’—which is nonsense, of course.

The preposition *at* is an interesting case in this connection. In general, adding the preposition is associated with spoken language and a somewhat colloquial register. But when the verb is the copula (*be*) and the preposition is *at*, there is the additional circumstance that the phrasing “where X is at” has somehow become extremely widespread (even in contexts where you would normally use *in* as the preposition) especially in [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English), being used in many cases where most dialects would simply have “where X is”.

This association has done a lot to stigmatise the collocation of *where* and *at*, since AAVE is one of the dialects traditionally most severely looked down upon as uncultured and uneducated.

Going off into wild speculation, I would guess that is why your customer reacted to your use of “where it’s at”, even though in all likelihood he would not have batted an eyelid at “I can’t find the box where it’s in right now” or other similar examples.

Comment: It is true that because we 'have the corresponding "full" phrase somewhere in the back of our heads, . . . we sometimes add the preposition anyway', and that there are no strong reasons for objecting to such harmless redundancy. It seems, however, that 'where it’s at' is sometimes used without the speaker's having anything in mind that would make *at* (rather than, say, *in*) the right preposition; in these cases *at* is not merely redundant, but outright out-of-place, and it is that usage that strikes some people as particularly problematic.

Comment: @jsw29 I’d say speakers who use it have some sort of generic location phrase subconsciously in their mind, and the broadest and most generic preposition to express location is ‘at’. It just means ‘located’ when used with the copula. Speakers that use the preposition presumably also do so because it allows them to maintain the verb in its unstressed/clitic form. Meanwhile, speakers who find it out of place only do so because it’s not part of _their own_ speech; there’s no other objective reason for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that part of his problem is ending the sentence (or clause) with a preposition. Correcting that would result in, "They can tell you at where it is." But that sounds insane. He wanted to avoid that by leaving out the "at," which could possibly change the meaning of the sentence.

But the rule against ending a sentence or phrase with a preposition is left over from Latin grammar, and I think a lot of experts think that rule is dumb and shouldn't apply to English.

Comment: Possibly, but the customer said, "You don't have to say *at*", not "You can't [or shouldn't] say *at*". In other words, the *at* is redundant.

Comment: It almost definitely is redundant, and I would never personally use "at" in that usage, but I'm sure someone can think of some example where the "at" adds meaning to the sentence.

Comment: I'd take "Can you tell me where they're at?" as being metaphorical without any context.

Comment: One possible (admittedly stylized and colloquial) use is like in Rakim saying "It ain't where you from, it's where you're at." Maybe the customer asked, "Hey, what is the next big cool thing that all the kids are doing?"

Comment: I wouldn't use it either, but that's because I'm so old I remember when *where it's at* was slang for something like right understanding, as in Bob Dylan's "Like a Rolling Stone" -- *Ain’t it hard when you discover that /
 He really wasn’t **where it’s at***.

Comment: Or the customer could be asking, "I understand that you have a robot that is currently reading the entire works of Shakespeare in chronological order. Can someone tell me how far it has gotten?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say, ‘They can tell you where it is.’”

If you say it this way, I think *everyone* will understand you, and no one will find what you said irritating.

If you say it your way, everyone will understand you, but a fair number of people will find it grating.

If you want to avoid this dilemma, you could say, 'They can help you find it.'

Comment: The question is whether the utterance is grammatical, not whether people will understand it, nor if someone might find it irritating or grating.

Answer (score 0):

First, ending a sentence with a preposition is technically incorrect. Most people do it and few people will complain about it.

More importantly, where and at are redundant, plain and simple. Where are you and where are you at mean the same thing in every context, so the 'at' should be dropped.

Repeat 'where you are' over and over, and I promise you, 'where you are at' will start to sound more and more incorrect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question already has a detailed, carefully written, and rather persuasive answer. In such a case, if one wishes to add another answer, on is expected to make it very clear how it differs from, or what it adds to, the already posted ones.

Comment: (1) Ending a sentence / fragment with a preposition is not incorrect per se (perhaps 'technically' equates to 'according to grammar arbitrarily demanded by some prescriptivist teachers 70 years ago'). This has been stated many, many times on ELU, Peter. // (2) That said, there are some situations where a poor-sounding result is produced by ending a sentence with a preposition. This one obviously is in the grey area. The question is, who decides acceptability? (See my first comment, made over 5 years ago.)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you? (present tense and is quite sufficient). Where are you at? Ending with a preposition? Hell no, someone is asking for where one is, (present tense)). One cannot be “is”and “at” at the time in the same sentence.

Same as, “where are you now” vs “where are you”? In that tense, “are now” is improper because are and now have the same meaning and repetitious but hey, I’m only a Queen’s English master. Say what you want and sound like a master of the Queen’s English or say what you want and sound like a master of where you is at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your statement was correct. In this case "at" means "located". So you basically said "Where it is located", which is grammatically correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).