# can who be used as the informal form of whom?

Tags: pronouns, formality, syntactic-analysis, relative-pronouns, whom

In a grammar book, there were two examples used to clarify the difference
between *who* and *whom*, and to show that *who* can be used as the informal form
of *whom*, and there would be no difference in meaning. The examples were:

> 1. Bob is the young man whom she interviewed. (*she interviewed whom/him*)
> 2. Bob is the young man who she interviewed. (*informal*)

It's stated that the second sentence is informal, but our teacher insists
that in the second sentence **Bob** interviewed **her** (that is, the woman)!

Can anyone tell me which one is true? Is it just informal or does the
meaning change? Is the woman always the interviewer, or do the roles switch in the second sentence so that now he interviews her instead of vice versa?

Comment: of interest: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57471/194281

Comment: I don’t see any way to get the second meaning from the second sentence; it would have to be “Bob is the young man who interviewed her.”

Comment: Your teacher is completely and utterly wrong, and clearly not a native speaker of English. _Who(m)_ is **optionally** marked for non-subject case in most contexts, but personal pronouns like _she/her_ are **mandatorily** marked for non-subject case in all contexts. So you can choose whether to use _who_ or _whom_ (or nothing at all, usually) as the object of a verb, but you cannot, under **any** circumstances, ever use _she_ instead of _her_ as the object of a verb.

Comment: Once we see 'she interviewed,' we know who took that action. We also commonly say "Bob is the young man she interviewed."

Comment: Incredible that a teacher would make this kind of error.  It would be curious to know what they're using as a reference to arrive at this kind of confusion.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for your complete and helpful explanation.. it really helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences mean **the same**. The first is the sort of English used by purists, and the second is modern English, seen in daily usage.

Your teacher, without doubt, is wrong.

Comment: Yes.. the book said so, and I myself thought the same way.. anyway, I wanted to make sure of it. Thank you for your help !