# About the 'as in'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> if "minus" is conceivably an operator, **as in** "the band reunited, minus one member", you would use the singular.

Which is preposition? the 'as' or 'in' or both as a whole is preposition? In English, can two preposition be used one after another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It often helps to complete such phrases, because filling in the omitted (or imagined to have been omitted) words can make the construction clearer.

In this case, *as in* stands for *as [it is] in*:

> If "minus" is conceivably an operator,
>   as [it is] in "the band reunited,
>   minus one member", you would use the
>   singular.

Then it is easy to see that *in* is a simple preposition, and *as* a conjunctive adverb. As Reg said, you could functionally consider the whole an adverb. Just as you could consider *black coffee* a noun. (I don't quite see the need for this invention, as it can be cut off by Occam's Razor.) Note that this is also the only satisfying way of analysing "as if": *he fled the city in a great hurry, as [he would do] if he were chased by bears; no wonder, after such a scandal*. Note that it is completely normal in countless cases to leave out words in comparisons with *as* and *than*.

Answer (score 4):

*In* is a preposition, but *as in* as a whole acts as a conjunctive adverb, [according to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_in).

As to your second question — yes, in English, two (and more) prepositions can be used one after another. For example, "Barack Obama stepped out from behind his teleprompter". Or, borrowing a leaf from [ShreevatsaR](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-okay-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition), "Daddy, what did you bring that book that I don't want to be read to out of about Down Under up for?"