# Ending a clause with a preposition, rule of thumb or hard rule?

Tags: prepositions, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When is it okay to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-okay-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

So we've all heard the admonishments from our teachers not to end a clause with a preposition

> A plumber visits a wealthy estate to fix a clogged toilet. As the butler opens the door, the plumber barks out,"I'm here to fix the toilet. Where's your bathroom at?"
>
> "Please try to speak with more discretion. We do not want to disturb our neighbors with the details of our plumbing issues. And we most certainly do not end our sentences with prepositions, sir.
>
> So the plumber lowers his tone and says more cordially, "I'm here to fix the toilet. Where's your bathroom at, asshole."

Anyway, back to the matter at hand. I have come under the impression that this is a rule of thumb to help the elementary student avoid mismatching case for the target of the preposition rather than a hard rule. For example by placing the preposition closer to its target, you avoid constructs like: "Who did you give the invitation to?" instead of the proper "To whom did you give the invitation?". Moving the preposition closer makes the incorrect case sound absurd. No one would ever say "To who did you give the invitation?"

All of this introductory text leads up to this simple question: Is this phrase correct "Whom did you give the invitation to?" or is it still incorrect english even though we addressed the issue of case?

Comment: A duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-okay-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition

Comment: Sorry it didn't pop up until I tagged my question with preposition.

Comment: Happens all the time, I'm sure:-)

Comment: I hope that was your Latin teacher that was admonishing you thus, a good English teacher would say no such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's a rule of thumb, to avoid students make errors.

The NOAD, in the note about the usage of *who* versus *whom* reports that

> The normal practice in modern English is to use *who* instead of *whom* and, where applicable, to put the preposition at the end of the sentence.
>   - *Who do you think we should support?*
>   - *Who do you wish to speak to?*

It also reports that

> Such uses are today broadly accepted in standard English, but in formal writing it is best to maintain the distinction.

As you are using *whom*, the correct sentence is

> To whom did you give the invitation?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the "normal practice" because it has become normal practice to use reflexive pronouns when they're not necessary.

"If you have a question, ask John or myself."

Comment: _myself_ is used also to emphasize the speaker; _If you have a question, ask John or myself_ seems as correct as _I myself am unsure how this problem should be handled_ is.

Comment: In the second example 'myself' reflects on 'I'. In the first myself is freestanding. People don't use it to add emphasis. They use it to avoid parsing whether they should use subjective or objective case. See http://www.dianahacker.com/bedhandbook6e/subpages/myself.html

Comment: @Mike Brown I don't think it is so simple with *myself* . *The Merriam-Webster Dictionary of English Usage* gives a long discussion of many different standard uses of *myself* http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PA338&ots=nYyVimuZU6&dq=Lurie%201927%20disapproves%20of%20using%20the%20verb%20diagnose%22&pg=PA647#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: The second example I reported was written in an English dictionary (_New Oxford American Dictionary_); I don't think they report examples that are not correct, and make them pass as correct.

Comment: Yes I agree that the second example is valid. My response was unclear. In the second example, it is used to add emphasis. The first example isn't used for emphasis but rather as a substitute for "me".

Comment: This is another example reported from the dictionary: _Myself presented to him a bronze sword._

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Is that in the NOAD? I can imagine it to be _I myself presented to him a bronze sword_ but not _Myself presented to him a bronze sword_.

Comment: @Tragicomic: The sentence I wrote is the one reported by the NOAD, which describes that usage as poetic or literary.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thanks for the clarification. Looked it up _myself_ and found it here :) http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0545620#m_en_gb0545620