# Terminal preposition / adposition question

Tags: prepositions, writing-style, prepositional-phrases

So I was hoping to know if the phrase

> as many as I can think **of**

is improper or incorrect because it ends with the word "of"?  What would be a way to *minimally* change this to not violate any don't-end-with-a-preposition guideline?

And yes - I know it's [not really a big problem to do this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118809/a-question-ending-with-preposition-of), I am just curious if there is a "proper" way to write it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to change "think of" for some alternative verb that doesn't end in "of", so instead of *(I just ended this sentence with of!)*

> as many as I can think of

maybe try

> as many as I can recall

or

> as many as I can imagine

depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the piece is formal or causal. For a formal writing, try, "as many of which I can think."

If that doesn't set right with you, try restructuring the sentence as previously suggested (ie: as many as I can imagine)

Comment: *"As many as I can think of"* returns 30 pages of Google hits. *"As many of which I can think"* returns none. This is not an improvement, even in formal writing.

Comment: Perhaps *as many **as** of which I can think* would be better? But, on the whole, I think this is just another example, should one be needed, of the problems caused by the injunction never to end a sentence with a preposition. Or, as someone once put it, "Trailing prepositions are something up with which I shall not put!"