# Who vs. Whom for: "...Satan, who/whom everyone imagines with horns."

Tags: grammatical-case

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the correct usage of “whom”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14761/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-whom)
>   [Using “who” and “whom”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/using-who-and-whom)

I'm not sure what the clause is called, but it usually describes something (such as Satan). I would think it's "whom" because, in this context, everyone is imagining *him* with horns. They don't imagine *he* with horns. That's how I reason it, but it's confusing at times.

Thoughts?

What if it were: "...Satan, who/whom everyone imagines has horns"? Would you use "who" or "whom"?

Comment: Hmm, so, yes I guess it's a duplicate of those questions, but the answers from those questions don't really help me determine what the correct case is especially for my 2nd question. :|

Comment: for both it's whom. I don't have a rule, I go with what feels right, so I can't elucidate as to why.

Comment: "everyone imagines him with horns" => whom