# "preposition: a word to annoy prescriptivists with"

Tags: meaning, jokes

What is the double meaning/meanings of this?

Answer (score 5):

Prescriptivists say you can't end a sentence with a preposition. The example sentence does.

Comment: However, go right ahead with ending a preposition or clause with a preposition!!

Comment: Since you can't end a Latin sentence with a preposition, the early prescriptive grammarians (like Bishop Lowth) decided it was wrong to do so in English. And everybody has pretty much ignored the "rule" ever since. However, the last word of a sentence is a great place to put a strong word, and a preposition will often end a sentence weakly. Expert English users will finish with a preposition when doing so hits the idiom.

Comment: I was told at a young age, "Never end a sentence a preposition with."

Comment: @all commenters: there's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-okay-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition) for that. Let's not rehash it all here.

Comment: I'd like to add that this well-known prescriptivist rule is a bit of a straw man fallacy: the more sophisticated, reasonable prescriptivists do not support this rule. I don't think I've ever met someone who would, and I knows me some prescriptivists.