# "He cannot be reasoned with"

Tags: prepositions

This is a phrase I hear extremely often, with some modifications to the subject. But it seems to be improper, because the sentence is ended with a preposition. What is the "correct" way to say this phrase?

Comment: [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/47/300)

Comment: “He cannot be reasoned with” is perfectly fine in both formal and informal speech. There is a style directive which prohibits this, and its introduction was artificial, but the rule is often enforced and so people tend to think of it as a real grammatical rule (the point is that it is just a style rule). To avoid ending in a preposition, move the pronoun to the preposition, "with him" and restructure the rest 'No one can/You can't reason with him'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the "rule" that a sentence should not ever end with a preposition is wrong, wrong, wrong.  (See [Grammar Girl's article on the matter](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/ending-prepositions.aspx).)

Second, if you still want to avoid it, you have to recast the sentence slightly:  "You cannot reason with him", or perhaps "No one can reason with him."

Comment: Interesting; would "to reason with" be considered one of these 'phrasal verbs' mentioned in the article you provided?

Comment: @Rickay: No, it is just a regular preposition. A phrasal verb is of the kind where the preposition can come at the end even in a simple sentence: *she put the suitcase down*. But you cannot say, *she reasoned him with*, not if this is the entire sentence.

Comment: Then would it not be possible to use the passive voice with this phrase while retaining grammatical correctness?

Answer (score 3):

Not everyone agrees that it is incorrect to end a sentence with a preposition. If you'd absolutely want to avoid it here though, then I would say "You cannot reason with him".