# "Can we get this over with?"

Tags: meaning, prepositional-phrases

I am confused about this sentence because it ends in a preposition, something that I thought was not really grammatically correct:

> Can we get this over with?

In addition, I haven't found a restatement that would solve this issue. Things like the following don't seem to make sense:

> This can we get over
>   Over with get this
>   With get this over

So my questions are:
1. Is there a problem with the sentence?
2. What part of speech is "with"?

Comment: 2. *With* is a preposition, as you state yourself. 1. Ending a sentence with a preposition is perfectly grammatical and has been [discussed before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition). 3. Rewriting advice is off-topic here.

Comment: 'Over' is a preposition, too. If it really bothers you, how about "Can we get this over with now?" ?

Comment: "This is the sort of arrant pedantry up with which I shall not put!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no problem with this phrase - it is idiomatic English.
2. *With* is part of the compound adjective *over with*. *To be over with* means *to be finished*. As far as I know, it's only ever used with the verb *be*.
3. It's fine as it is. You could say "Can we get this finished?".

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you really want to, you can rewrite it as:

> Over with can we get this?

but you end up sounding like you're chanelling Yoda.

So thank you for providing an excellent refutation of the "never end a sentence with a preposition" rule.  Next time somebody tries to tell me how to speak English, I'll take a deep breath and say, "Okay.  Over with let us get this..."  :-)