# Could someone explain to me the difference between "based upon"/"based on" and "according to"?

Tags: differences, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, example

I am assuming "based upon" and "based on" are basically the same phrase.

In my language, "based upon" and "according to" have pretty much the same translation. What is actually the difference?

Could anyone explain this to me? Are there any example sentences that you could give me to show the difference?

EDIT: I am not sure why this is being voted down. I am here to learn, and these two phrases are very similar in Mandarin Chinese. Sorry.

Comment: There were no down votes to this question. Simply no up votes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, *according to*[[1](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.denverlibrary.org/view/Entry/1177?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=UCceo0&)] is the usage of the words *according* and *to* as a compound preposition. The definition of the adjective *according* is:

> ```
>  1. With to. Corresponding to something; agreeing, matching. Obs.*
>  5. As a compound preposition. according to: as stated or formulated by.
> ```

The word *according* itself means:

> 2. Suitable, fitting, appropriate; in accordance with something previously stated.

So *according to* would mean: "in accordance with", "suitable to", "appropriate to",  etc.

---

*Based on* and *based upon* do have similar meanings, there's a good question about it [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/based-on-vs-based-upon).

Oxford English Dictionary describes base[[2](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.denverlibrary.org/view/Entry/15848?)] used as a figurative:

> 12. fig.
>
> > ```
> > a. A fundamental principle, an underlying basis, a foundation
> > b. A ground for an action or attitude; an underlying reason or justification.
> > ```

They don't mention the compound usages of *based upon* and *based on*, but the meaning can be inferred. Merriam Webster describes a definition of base for kids as:

> — base on or base upon
>
> > :  to make or form from a starting point < It's based on a true story. >

According to states that the following statement or idea is something someone or something would agree with or have conveyed themselves.  Based upon states that the following idea, statement, or work is built off of something else.

Another way to look at: *according to* is attempting to paraphrase or quote someone or something, while *based* on or *based upon* is creating a separate idea, work, or statement that has been influenced by or has been structured from the original.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is one of trustworthiness.

**Based on...**
**Based upon...**

is an appeal to available evidence.  Even if the appeal is to a named source, Merriam-Webster, or Berthon and Onions, it is the work that is referred to.

**According to...**

is an appeal to an authority. You can even say "According to Freud XYZ, but according Jung ABC," and then disagree with both.

I think it follows that "based on" can almost always be replaced by "according to," but not every "according to" can be replaced by "based on."

Comment: *Based on/upon* refers to a "source", whilst *According to* refers to "conformance". Example: the software is based on user's requirements. It was developed according to specifications.