# Where to put the preposition of "approve"?

Tags: prepositions, word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

In [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20622/6879) I wrote

> [You can use it] to take pictures of a movie in a cinema, of which the
>   cinema guys probably wouldn't approve.

but I am not sure if it should rather be

> [You can use it] to take pictures of a movie in a cinema, which the
>   cinema guys probably wouldn't approve of.

I found [this page](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/preps-placement.html) but I'm still unable to find out which example it relates to. (... to which example it relates?)

Comment: This is the old 'don't end a sentence with a preposition' debate. Both your sentences are grammatical standard English, the 'of which' one sounding a little more formal, but both are accepted in speech. In newspapers and technical writing I'm not sure.

Comment: Furthermore, leaving off the _of_ at the end is **also** grammatical, since by the time one gets to the end of the sentence, one has normally forgotten whether there should be something there, and leaving it off is shorter. After all, _approve_ **can** take a direct object, as in _Would you approve this, please, so I can move on?_ That means that _... which the cinema guys probably wouldn't approve_ is also OK.

Comment: I don't want to get mired in the grammatical/ungrammatical controversy itself, but I personally feel OP's first version is at best "ungainly", because **to approve of** is a complete, self-contained [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb). Moving *"of"* to the front, and tacking a subject noun phrase in before *"approve"* grates on my ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are technically correct, but the latter sounds more natural (especially because your sentence is informal in nature):

> [You can use it] to take pictures of a movie in a cinema, which the
>   cinema guys probably wouldn't approve of.

The idea that it is not desirable to end a sentence with a preposition has no real basis. As Winston Churchill put it:

> From now on, ending a sentence with a preposition is something up with which I will not put.

Of course, Churchill's phrase is extremely awkward; the more natural equivalent being:

> From now on, ending a sentence with a preposition is something I will not put up with.

Or, at least:

> From now on, ending a sentence with a preposition is something with which I will not put up.

Comment: That phrase is not Churchill's. That's [a misattribution no longer to be put up with](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html).