# There is a new search of which I've become aware / .. I've become aware of?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

I would like to know which is correct and why:

> There is a new search of which I've become aware.

or

> There is a new search I've become aware of.

Comment: "I've become aware of a new search"

Comment: @Henry, yes I know but I am interested in these variants.

Comment: You could [look it up](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004454.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible English sentences, but the first is perhaps more likely to be found in formal contexts.

Comment: thanks, I assume in this context "of which" is not possisive like "whose"..?

Comment: @Pietroo: ‘Possessive’ is not always a very helpful or accurate grammatical description anyway, but the point here is simply that the verb is ‘be aware OF’.

Answer (score 1):

I think the latter is often used, because some of us were taught in grammar school that prepositions were not words to end sentences with.  So, when we encounter a sentence that terminates with a preposition, we apply a knee-jerk "fix" to the problem, by using the construct in your latter example (even though Henry's edit would have been better).  Hence,

> *Prepositions are not words to end sentences with*.

becomes

> *Prepositions are not words with which to end sentences*.

which may have kept our middle-school grammar teacher happy, even though

> *Don't end sentences with prepositions*.

would be the better correction.