# Ending sentence with "supposed to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Is the following sentence acceptable?

> He arrived ten minutes earlier than he was **supposed to**.

It doesn't sound right, but I can't think of any better way to end the sentence.

Comment: Related: [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly correct. If you don't like the sound of it you could make it more elegant (in my opinion) by changing it to:

> He arrived ten minutes earlier than he was supposed to have done.

Comment: ...supposed to have *done*? I don't think this is quite right, I think it should be just ...supposed to have

Comment: @Armen: different dialects. I think people from the UK like to stick "have done" on the end of sentences like this, where we'd just use "have" in the US.

Comment: @PeterShor: Oh, I see, I have been exposed to US Media much more than to British, so maybe that's why it hit the ear wrong

Comment: You could add “…supposed to arrive”, “…supposed to have”, or “…supposed to have arrived” to make this answer more complete.

Comment: Is *...than he should have* any better?

Comment: Why use "have" when implicitly, the word elided is "arrive?"  That is: "He arrived ten minutes earlier than he was supposed to arrive."

Comment: @Thomas, You could say we're paraphrasing "He was supposed to have arrived 10 minutes later". Also, kurkevan wants this to "sound right" and I don't think repeating a verb in the same sentence sounds very elegant.

Answer (score 5):

> [**to be supposed to do something**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suppose): be required to do something because of the position one is in or an agreement one as made
>
> - I am supposed to be meeting someone at the airport.

So, you can understand the sentence by re-writing it as:

> He arrived ten minutes earlier than he was **required to**.

It is completely *correct*.

Answer (score 4):

It's acceptable. "Supposed to" has always looked strange to me in writing. You could extend it out to "...supposed to have." but I don't really think there's much helping the feeling except getting used to using the phrase.

Comment: Is "to" technically a preposition when used in an infinitive? I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: I'm not either.

Comment: Ah, according to this: http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/particleterm.htm "to" in an infinitive is a "particle."

Answer (score 2):

I guess it does break the (pointless and stupid) rule against ending a sentence with a preposition. Despite that, it seems like a perfectly good sentence to me. That would be very hard to re-word to avoid that problem.

You could say, "He arrived ten minutes earlier than he was supposed to arrive," but that sounds clumsy with "arrive" used twice in such a brief space.

You could, I guess, say, "He arrived ten minutes earlier than he was expected" or some other totally different word.

I'd keep it as is.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> He arrived ten minutes earlier than he had planned.

It has a slightly different connotation, but if you think "supposed to" is a bit unwieldy perhaps this works better?