# "Where are you now at?" — grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Should I say "Where are you at now?" or "Where are you now at?"

Which is grammatically correct? And is there any difference in meaning between the two?

Comment: Are these at all correct forms? There's no noun for "at" to go with. I would think you'd rather say either "Where are you now" or "What are you at now". I'd welcome other people's takes on this.

Comment: I was going to answer that I was told not to end a sentence with a preposition, but... I found this question. Read the first answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition

Comment: @evgeny I think that the noun is "you".

Comment: The object of "at" in this sentence is "where".

Comment: Related Language Log post: [“Where we're at”](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4125).

Comment: Both are common but common idiom isn't the same as grammatical correctness. Where did your own research take you and when did it fail, pleae?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are possible in speech, although the first is probably more likely. They can be:

a) an inquiry about someone's location;

b) an inquiry about someone's mental, spiritual or emotional state; or

c) an inquiry about which page someone has reached in a book.

Answer (score 4):

Neither example feels very comfortable grammatically although I feel this is perhaps a BE view. We used to say 'a preposition should never be used to end a sentence with.' In fact, the use of ***at*** in either case seems redundant since both examples make sense without it.

Comment: 1. [The supposed rule against ending a sentence with a preposition is not, and never was, correct](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition). 2. Redundancy is not a failure of communication, but rather an essential part of it.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I was careful in my reply not to be dogmatic although I feel you have tended towards it yourself. There is no absolute rule for either of your statements and, if you down-voted the answer, it seems a little unfair.

Comment: Ah, don't let what's fair or unfair bother you too much here on StackExchange, that'll just drive you mad :) Take a downvote as a sign that people care enough to read your answer and give it some thought. On the matter at hand: my opinion is that your answer wasn't as helpful to the questioner as it might have been, since although you said neither form feels comfortable, you didn't give clear suggestions as to what might be better.

Comment: @MarkBeadles There I go being over-sensitive! Thanks.

Comment: You're right, Tony. Both examples make sense without the word *at*. From a British perspective, at least. It's an unnecessary, added extra. I suspect that it is an example of American English.

Answer (score -2):

Neither is correct. Never end a sentence with the word "at". 
"Where are you now?" Or "Where are you?" 
There is no reason to add "at" to this sentence.