# Using “at” at the end of “where” questions

Tags: where

Is there any difference in meaning between these two sentences? Is it only a matter of style?

*1. Where are you?*

*2. Where are you at?*

Comment: I’d expect #1 to be asking about location, but you’ll need to supply more context to work out what #2 means.

Comment: The _at_ is grammatically unnecessary, but see https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/where+it%27s+at

Comment: The answer to either could be, "I'm halfway through the fourth chapter," or "I've just finished the second round of trial tests." The answer could also be (more traditionally), "I'm at the office." In short, the *at* makes no essential difference.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!  So this is how I understand now. Adding _at_ is grammatically correct but not necessary. It makes no difference in the meaning. _Where it’s at_ is an interesting idiom, which is new to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Where are you now at?" — grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76209/where-are-you-now-at-grammatically-correct) Some dictionaries (mainly British) add the caveat 'informal' to at least one related pairing of 'where' and 'at'. Adding 'at' almost always signals a metaphorical usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Where are you?*

This construction usually refers to your physical location.  It is grammatically correct.

2. *Where are you at?*

This construction is likely to refer to how far through a particular task you are, such as reading a book, travelling somewhere, or thinking about a problem.  This construction is a colloquial idiom, and is not correct in formal English.  It would usually be tautological and grammatically incorrect to use the preposition "at" with the word "where" but this particular construction ("Where are you at?") has gained currency in informal communication.