# ending a sentence with a preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions, poetry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

"a soul can sense when it’s being talked to."

Does this sound OK? I don't like ending with a preposition, but it does get the point across. Any suggestions to replacing the phrase "being talked to"

Thanks

After reading similar questions on this topic, Edward Tanguay referenced a site, http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition.html
which basically states to avoid confusion try not ending with a preposition. So I'll change it from:

"a soul can sense when it’s being talked to."

to one of these:

"a soul can sense when it’s being summoned."

"a soul can sense when it’s being addressed."

Not exactly the meaning I wanted, but gets the preposition out of the way.

Thanks,