# Are these consecutive prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

> If Gryffindor won, they would move (1) **up into** second place in the
>   house championship.  (Harry Potter book1)
>
> They follow him (2) **out into** the farmyard, and (3) **on into**
>   the old flint barn. (The Secret Intensity of Everyday Life)

Are those examples of (1), (2) and (3) the same consecutive prepositions as the case in [J.R.’s reply](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90211/can-two-prepositions-be-used-one-after-the-other)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first example of “move up into second place” is a phrasal verb, *to move up* followed by a preposition.

There is nothing “wrong”, nor even uncommon, with stacking prepositions in English. You can lean **out of** a second-storey window, or ask someone to come **on up out of** the cellar — or even, and somewhat famously, ask them what they brought that book that you don’t want to be read **to out of up for**.

Comment: AHDEL classifies _out of_ as a single ('complex') preposition; cf _on top of_, the obsolescent _over against_, and the (arguably 'simple') fused form _into_ (and many others). _Come on up out of the cellar_ arguably contains a particle, an adverb, and the complex preposition _out of_.