# "Optional machines to work with"

Tags: meaning

My point in the quoted sentence is to introduce a new section where I will list all the machines that are currently available for a given task.

> Optional machines to work with

Is the sentence above conveying my point?
Secondly, is it idiomatic as written right now?

Comment: Ending a sentence with a preposition has been discussed on ELU at length (see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition), for example). However, you don't have a sentence in your question, you have a clause (or perhaps a section header). If it's a mere section header, I think you'd be better off using the simpler _Optional machines_, although it's difficult to say for sure with so little context provided.

Comment: I have removed the part that was a clear dupe of the question J.R. linked to.

Comment: My problem was, are these machines that process options? Or are they optionally available? Or does it mean yet something else?

Comment: I'm not sold on using *optional* here. It conveys the idea that it's OK if you don't pick any, but the way I get the context it's not OK. Why not stick with *available*?

Comment: Can you give more detail about the type of machines? My gut feeling would be to go along with something shorter like: "Other tools", but it depends on the context.

Comment: The scenario is something like the following you have your own machine but in need you can use the other ones which are meant for that purpose.

Comment: "Machines available for use".

Comment: Or, "Other available machines".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start and finish with,

- *Optional machines to work with*

is not an English sentence.

It is an English Noun Phrase, with an undetermined head noun *machines*, modified by an ambiguous modal adjective *optional* --  optionality of the *work* or the *machines*? -- and a subjectless relative infinitive clause *to work with*.

There are a lot of ambiguities and missing referents in this noun phrase that must be resolved by the (hopefully well-trained) reader. With that many problems already, I don't think the risk of additional outrage over a stranded preposition is even worth considering.

**Executive Summary:** Start over.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the machines made a lot more sense than the particular noun-phrase you use.

With the limited information you've given, I'd suggest "**Alternative machines/tools available**".