# Is this a proper use of a semicolon and the word "whom"?

Tags: grammar, semicolons, whom

> PCAs are usually assigned to an individual with a physical, mental, behavioral, or emotional handicap; whom they work with throughout the year.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? I know that semicolons are sometimes used when you have a list at the beginning of the sentence, to prevent confusion. Is that accurate?

Also, would "who" or "whom" be proper in this usage? I thought it would be "whom" because it's referring to the person who is helped, not the person who is helping, but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don’t want a semi-colon there. A comma will do. *Whom* is grammatical, but so, too, would *who* be in an informal context.

Comment: This seems to me a formal enough context to require *whom*; I wonder if it is formal enough to need *with whom they work*.

Comment: @TimLymington - "I wonder if it is formal enough to need _with whom they work_" - see the answers to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition).

Comment: @dj18; Nice catch but, since this isn't the end of the sentence, irrelevant. The point is whether the relative should precede the pronoun it refers to/to which it refers.  In much formal language the answer is no.

Comment: But who decides the degree of formality that necessitates these 'requires', 'needs' and 'shoulds'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. The writer.

Comment: Tim doesn't seem to agree.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be tempted to use a dash after the heavily-commaed list, merely for ease on the reader's eye:

PCAs are usually assigned to an individual with a physical, mental, behavioral, or emotional handicap - whom they work with throughout the year.

(I *wouldn't* suggest the use here of a semi-colon as a 'super comma', though I'm happy to use it thus in lists containing sub-lists.) I would read the following two sentences differently:

Trainee dog-trainers often have to deal with dogs with physical, mental, behavioural, or emotional problems, which they work with throughout the year.

Trainee dog-trainers often have to deal with dogs with physical, mental, behavioural, or emotional problems - which they work with throughout the year.

Answer (score 0):

If you like the semicolon as a break between the comma-separated list and the next clause, you need to convert that clause from dependent to independent:

> PCAs are usually assigned to an individual with a physical, mental, behavioral, or emotional handicap; they work with this person throughout the year.