# who or whom in this context?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

I am unsure which is the grammatically correct one in the following context:

> ...trying to find a programmer with *who* / *whom* I could collaborate.

Which one is the correct usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, "with whom" is grammatically correct, but most native Anglophones would probably say this:

> "I'm trying to find a programmer that I can collaborate with."

It avoids the "who/whom" problem and it's more natural English.

Comment: Prepositions are never good words to end sentences with.

Comment: Nonsense. They're frequently just what you want to finish up with.

Comment: The only situation in English grammar where *whom* is required is as the object of a preposition that immediately procedes it. As *with* does here. So *with whom* is grammatical, and **with who* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Sparr whether that is nonsense or not (it is), there's a [dedicated question for that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition). Please stay on topic. Thank you.

Comment: But, as Bill points out, a relative pronoun like *who(m)* is ordinarily moved to the front of a relative clause, and if that relative pronoun turns out to be the object of a preposition like *with*, it's perfectly OK to strand *with* at the end of the clause, instead of going to the extra formal trouble of Pied-Piping it along with *who(m)* to the beginning of the clause.  
But if you **do** go to all that trouble, you have to use *whom* to show how formal it is.

Comment: @RegDwighт John got the joke...