# Using a verb +prep in a sentence with prepositions at the front

Tags: prepositions

If you are avoiding ending a sentence with prepositions ("That was a situation, in which it was better to not become entangled."), what happens if you use a verb with a preposition? Suppose I wanted to say "This is something we will not put up with." Should I say "This is something with which we will not put up." since *put* and *up* form a phrasal verb, or should I say "This is something up with which we will not put"?

Comment: Duplicate of [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that if you insist on following the nonsensical rule, then you'll have to say *up with which we will not put*, like the [famous example (probably wrongly) attributed to Winston Churchill](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill#Disputed).

Note that the phrasal verb here is *put up with*, not *put up*, which has a number of meanings, all of them different from *put up with*. For this reason *something with which we will not put up*, though grammatical, is confusing and likely not to be understood.

The **English** for these is *which we will not put up with*.

Comment: Also note that the reason why this particular quote is so famous (and cheeky) is that avoiding clause-final prepositions _is simply not possible_ in English with phrasal verbs that end in prepositions. ‘Up with which’ has become common enough to be understood, but something like “This is the party forward to which I have been looking” or “That’s the coworker in for whom I’ve been sitting” is only valid English if you’re a 900-year-old green creature from a swamp planet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: good point, which I had lost sight of.