# phrasal verb or preposition at the end of a sentence?

Tags: prepositions

"That bullet point is simply in place to ensure that projects are followed through with."

I got blasted for ending the above sentence with with, and I feel it's a phrasal verb so is okay.  Am I correct?  The disclaimer here is that I'm terrible with the English language (probably seen in my question itself).

Thanks ahead of time for the assistance

Comment: You're right, and nothing you (or we) can say will persuade your blaster otherwise. That's theology, not grammar.

Comment: The reasoning "it's a phrasal verb so is okay" is complete nonsense, though. The sentence is fine as stated no matter whether you label *with* a part of a phrasal verb (which it clearly isn't) or a preposition (which it clearly is). You can label it Susan if it makes you happy, and you can still end the sentence exactly as stated.

Comment: You can just say "projects are followed through"; there's no need for the "with".

Comment: Right. _Follow through_ is a phrasal verb, but it's normally intransitive, and the _with_ is a transitivizing preposition. Since that makes _projects_ the affectd direct object (even though it's the object of a preposition), Passive can apply to it, producing the sentence in question, which has the same structure as _This bed was slept in by George Washington_, or _This sentence has been done things to._

Comment: @John: Isn't *follow through* normally used transitively? From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/follow) **follow something through**:
*continue an action or task to its conclusion.*

Comment: @PeterShor: Sorry, our responses collided. I was referring to RegDwigнt's comment, just above yours. _Follow through_ can be used transitively, but the construction with _with_ seems to be equally common (and more familiar to me). In any event, if it's a phrasal verb, it's frozen enough for Passive to affect it.

Comment: Of course, the classic response to your blaster would be [_Up with this I will not put_](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html).

Comment: @John Lawler I am not sure that we are of the same mind on what is an 'intransitive verb'. I may be wrong but I had always thought an intransitive was one which never took a direct object, such as 'sleep'. You cannot sleep anything - not directly at any rate. But there is nothing to say it can't take an indirect object. 'I sleep until noon', for example. But it can also take the preposition 'with'. 'I sleep with my wife' (just to keep matters decorous). But in this instance 'my wife' is an indirect object. So why do you say 'the "with" is a transitivizing preposition'?.

Comment: _Transitive_ means it **does** have a direct object, as well as a subject -- two arguments. _Intransitive_ means it **doesn't** have a direct object, just a subject -- one argument. _Bitransitive_ (some prefer _ditransitive_; I don't) means it has **two** objects, one direct and one indirect, as well as the obligatory subject. See the [Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for details.

Answer (score -1):

The verb is *follow through*. It doesn't need *with*.

Comment: ..., the answer to OP's underlying question of course being, he can still end the sentence just like he did. He is wrong, but so is his blaster. Ending a sentence in a preposition is perfectly grammatical, but we already have [a question on that](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/47/300).

Comment: Why is he wrong? _Follow through with_ is perfect conversational English.

Comment: @JohnLawler *Follow through with [something]* is conventional, but the *[something]* is necessary. In the OP quote, it's not supplied so *with* is not needed. I have a feeling this may be an AmE/BrE difference, though.

Comment: I agree the something has to be in the sentence, but it is; it's the subject of the passive clause. It's been moved, that's all. Like the _To_ in _To which do you refer?_ (though by Passive, not by Pied-Piping).

Comment: @JohnLawler, the asker is right too believe that the sentence is perfectly fine, but wrong in his reason to do so. More specifically, he is wrong that ‘with’ is part of the phrasal verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Not a transitive phrasal verb, certainly; _with_ doesn't appear on phrasal verbs, and this one doesn't commute: _Follow through with it_ ~ _*Follow through it with_ ~ _*Follow  it through with_. But _follow through_ is arguably a phrasal verb, and the whole construction is frozen enough to license the use of Passive. You're correct; just saying _Phrasal Verb_ solves nothing. There are too many varieties of construction, and far too many spurious understandings and definitions of the term.

Comment: I'd say ‘follow through’ is certainly a phrasal verb, and ‘with’ initiates a prepositional phrase tacked on to it (just like in ‘keep it up’ vs. ‘keep up with it’)—the thing the asker did wrong was to assume that if this is the case, then the sentence shouldn't be able to end with ‘with’, which is the same old north-Italian City we've all seen and heard so many times before all over again. :-)

Comment: As an active, if unlikely, construction it would be _That bullet point is simply in place to ensure that [staff] follow through projects_. No _with_.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I believe in Britain we tend to use follow-up (hyphenated) where Americans 'follow through' (non-hyphenated). The principal British meaning of 'follow-through' (hyphenated) is  in golf, cricket and possibly tennis, to describe what happens after the ball is hit. The OED do refer, briefly, to the figurative use but none of the synonyms seem apt enough to use. I think the QE way of expressing this would be: 'The bullet point is in place...to ensure that projects are followed-up.' Most certainly 'with' is not required.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence is correct without the "with" at the end.  The complaint was probably about ending with a preposition. But here, it's unnecessary.

Comment: It's unnecessary if your personal lexicon contains transitive _follow through_. If it contains only intransitive _follow through_ then _with is required.