# What would be proper grammar for this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Could you please tell me how to properly write the following sentence?  I believe I know the grammar rule but I must not be creative enough to think of an alternative sentence structure.  Here's the sentence:

> I would love to see houses you've been looking at.

I've never really figured out how to change a sentence like this without sounding really pompous.  Such as, "I would love to see houses at which you've been looking". This sentence sounds weird and awkward to me.

Comment: What's wrong with the original? Bothered by that "at" at the end? If so, [don't be](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your angst is over the so-called grammar rule about prepositions at the end of sentences, I think the sentence reads fine as is. However, if you really wanted to change something, why do all that rearranging of words? Trying taking out the two-word phrasal verb instead, and substitute a one-word synonym in its place:

> I would love to see the houses you've been viewing.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin; the sentence reads better with "the" in front of _houses_.

Comment: *Viewing* is not the same as *looking at*, at least in some contexts.

Comment: @Kris - Sure. If it's not the same meaning, though, one can simply choose different word – one that is more suitable. If that's not possible, the sentence can be left as-is.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> I would love to see the houses you've been looking at.

Note the addition of *the*. The "rule" about not ending a sentence with a preposition has no basis in usage before or after it was put forth. This sentence is a good example of one that cannot avoid ending with a preposition without being a pompous ass.

Without *the*, the sentence you had implies you don't want to see all the houses, but even then I would use *some of the houses* or *a few of the houses*.