# Am I able to finish a sentence with 'for'?

Tags: word-order

Am I able to finish a sentence with 'for'? eg. "...age that had long since disappeared but the return of which they desperately yearned for."

Comment: Yes, but you are using several constructions in your sentence that make it more complicated; the fact that you also have to wait until the last word of the sentence for all the complex constructions to fall into place renders the whole unwieldy. Here is doesn't work very well, but, in a simpler sentence, it may be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Of course you can. Why would you think you can't?

Comment: @dave: broken sarcasm detector or not, you do not need to explain that to the people on this site. We [know that alright](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition). (And please don't help spread that Churchill myth, it's common knowledge by now that [he never said that](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html).)

Comment: And at the OP: what do you mean, are you able to? You just did, so apparently the answer is yes. If you have something different in mind, please clarify by editing the question, then it can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can start or finish a sentence with 'for' as long as you have a context for it somewhere in the sentence, because 'for' is a conjunction as well as a preposition.

A Preposition is a word governing, and *usually* but not *always* preceding, a noun or pronoun, and expressing a relation to another word or element in the clause.

E.g.:

Was this the answer you were looking **for**?

Now, this is exactly what I was looking **for**!

Comment: +1, with minor edits, **for which** I am waiting approval. Edit Approval is what I am waiting **for**.

Comment: "What did you bring that book I didn't want to be read to out of up for?"