# Who do I need to send product information to?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> Who do I need to send product information to?

Comment: If I were to improve this sentence, I'd change "Who" to "Whom" before worrying about "to".

Comment: There's really no right or wrong answer on this one. Some style guides insist that you absolutely shouldn't end a sentence with _to_ (in which case your sentence should be "To whom are you attached?"), while others are vehement that the "no ending sentences with prepositions" rule is a useless, made-up rule that nobody needs to follow. If you are writing for a teacher or editor, it all depends on which rules they go by.

Comment: As Emily Brewster, editor at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/index.php) says: "A preposition is a perfectly appropriate kind of word to end a sentence **with**". :-)

Comment: All this said, yes, nobody will come and shoot you if you end a sentence with *to*.  But if you'd like my two cents, I'd say *To whom are you attached?* as that sounds better to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Answer (score 12):

You can end a sentence with a preposition if you want to.

> A visitor to Harvard stopped a student on the Yard and asked, "Can you tell me where the library's at?"
>
> The student replied, "At Harvard, we do not end sentences with prepositions."
>
> The visitor thinks a moment and rephrases his question.  "Can you tell me where the library's at, asshole?"

Answer (score 5):

Bryan Garner, the preeminent stylist of our times, says:

> [The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style](https://books.google.ca/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA266&dq=churchill%20%22ending%20a%20sentence%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m85CVZmCIdXfsATCx4G4Aw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=churchill%20%22ending%20a%20sentence%20with%22&f=false)  By Bryan A. Garner
>
> Winston Churchill's witticism about the absurdity of this bugaboo
>   should have laid it to rest. When someone once upbraided him for
>   ending a sentence with a preposition, he rejoined, **"That is the type
>   of arrant pedantry up with which I shall not put.**"
>
> [read more at that page]

Churchill is a good reference, quoted by many, e.g.,:

> [Franklin Covey Style Guide for Business and Technical](https://books.google.ca/books?id=fd1CnmaFD80C&pg=PA242&dq=churchill%20%22ending%20a%20sentence%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m85CVZmCIdXfsATCx4G4Aw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=churchill%20%22ending%20a%20sentence%20with%22&f=false)- Page 242
>   Stephen R. Covey, ‎Breck England - 2012 -
>
> Winston Churchill was once corrected for ending a sentence with a
>   preposition, and he supposedly replied, “**That is the sort of English
>   up with which I will not put.**”

Further:

> Law Notes for the General Practitioner - Volume 1 - Page xviii 1975
>
> I still do not like to split the infinitive, although it is common
>   practice these days, but **I have no objection to ending a sentence
>   with "to," nor did Winston Churchill**.