# How to say this properly?

Tags: grammar

"The tree is what I am looking at." No not formal enough.

"The tree is at what I am looking." Formal but sounds misleading.

I know I can easily say it like " I am looking at the tree." But just want to find out if there is anything wrong with saying it the second way. ???

Comment: "The tree is what I am looking at." No, not formal enough. [**Why not?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: The first is fine. The second is horrible.  *the tree is the focus of my attention.*  if you must.

Comment: @J.R.I assume it’s because it ends with a preposition.  Sigh.

Comment: “The tree is at what I am looking” is not formal. It's gibberish. It's completely ungrammatical. Why on earth do you need a specifically formal-only way to say this (as opposed to a neutral one, one which can be used both formally and informally)? Looking at a tree is not a particularly formal thing to be doing.

Comment: If you want something that sounds more formal than "look at," you could say _The tree is what I am observing._ Then you don't have to worry about the placement of prepositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to look at
to listen to
to leave for

The above are some verbs that use a preposition. Normally, in constructions such as yours, the preposition is placed at the end, although ending a sentence with a preposition is not preferred for some (that's probably from where you got the impression "not formal").

"The tree is what I am looking at." is correct. Alternatively, "It's the tree I'm looking at." or simply, "I'm looking at the three."

"The tree is at what I am looking."  or
"Jazz music is to what I'm listening." or
"London is for what I'm leaving."

These are improper constructions, when the verb takes a preposition. With no preposition, there's no such question, as in: "This is what I'm planning."

Comment: yoda speak they are

Comment: Think so, too, but haven't heard anyone speak that way.