# Is "Deals you'll want to tell everyone" correct?

Tags: prepositions

We have a VW billboard in here Melbourne advertising

> [Deals you'll want to tell everyone](http://www.adnews.com.au/campaigns/vw-brings-you-deals-you-ll-want-to-tell-everyone-about)

It's a fairly big-budget campaign so I assume the grammar has been thought out, but it just sounds off to me - can you 'tell everyone deals' or do you 'tell everyone *about* deals' or 'tell everyone *of* deals'? Can I *tell someone deals* the same way I could, say, *tell someone facts*?

The page I linked to above actually has the *about* in the title, but for the most part the campaign doesn't use prepositions in that location.

Comment: I wouldn't assume they thought it out well. In advertising, syntax and usage are often secondary (or tertiary, quaternary, or entirely off the radar). So you're right—the grammar is wrong on the billboard. Just don't expect to get a result if you point this out to the advertiser. (Go ahead and try, but don't get your hopes up.)

Comment: I actually think that this is one of those cases when someone perfectly fluent in English wrote up a perfectly grammatical sentence, and then some idiot came along and removed the last word to make it ungrammatical, and when asked why, replied "because it's a preposition" rather than "because I'm an idiot", [because he's an idiot](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/47/300). I am 100% sure it went down exactly like that.

Comment: I agree with you and @BrianHitchcock. The phrase has some emptyness. If I were you, I'd *show the deal to everyone.*  LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been:

1. Deals you'll want to talk about
2. Deals you'll want everyone to know (of)
3. Deals you'll want to tell everyone (about)

The *about* in the last option has been omitted to keep the sentence short in the form of a tagline which still withholds the basic idea of the line. Taglines are preferred to be short and catchy. The omitted *about* only highlights its informal call and urgency to tell people to hurry and have a look. It is just similar to saying "Hurry! Offer valid while stock lasts" instead of "Hurry! Offer is valid while the stock lasts".