# is stranding prepositions incorrect?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I recently came across this issue. I searched online and found that a stranded preposition might be no longer treated as incorrect, but it's just a guess. Are you still taught not to end a sentence with a preposition or is it a myth now?

Comment: [Well-explained here.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: It never was incorrect in the first place. What are you even talking about?