# What is the proper structure for the sentence "Whose dog does this ball belong to?"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

As I understand, keeping prepositions from the end of a sentence is a cardinal rule with no exceptions.  However, "To whose dog does this ball belong?" does not seem correct to me at all.  How should this sentence be structured?

Comment: That "rule" has been discredited. It is based on arbitrary stylistic concerns, not grammar.

Comment: Related question, [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "cardinal rule" is a myth that needs to be put to rest. It makes me think of ***This is the sort of English up with which I will not put!***

I wouldn't say *"To whose dog does this ball belong"* is ungrammatical (just awkward), but *"Whose dog does this ball belong to?"* is much more natural and idiomatic.

From a blog article at oxforddictionaries.com:

> ...there are four main types of situation in which it is more natural to end a sentence or clause with a preposition:
>
> - passive structures (*she enjoys being fussed over*)
> - relative clauses (*they must be convinced of the commitment that they are taking on*)
> - infinitive structures (*Tom had no-one to play with*)
> - **questions beginning with who**, where, what, etc. (*what music are you interested in?*)

([Grammar myths #1: is it wrong to end a sentence with a preposition?](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/))

Comment: @Hugh Is that relevant to the question?

Comment: The "on" in the second example ("...they are taking on") looks more like an adverb than a preposition to me.

Comment: @Hugh I'm not making an argument based on etymology but on usage. My argument is enclosed in sentence #2, *This is the sort of English up with which I will not put!*. That's it. Now, I have no reason to question the reasoning in the oxforddictionaries.com post, but I quoted only the relevant part, which I think is a nice summary of obvious cases where a stranded preposition is idiomatic.

Comment: No, I know you're not. But since the "cardinal rule" was held so fiercely and for so long I thought it worth saying that it was not simply made up to annoy schoolchildren,  It is based on rhetorical advice not to end a paragraph with a weak word because, if you do, it just sort of tails off.

Comment: Andreas Blass, it might be interpreted as a phrasal verb.