# Is it formal to say "I've met people I was able to connect with"?

Tags: grammaticality, formality

I would like to say the following:

> "During my daily work I’ve met many interesting people I was able to
>   connect with."

Is this right in a formal way?

What I would like to say is that I did some networking during my work period but in some sort of reflection atmosphere, if that makes any sense.

Edit: 
How about that one?

> "During my daily work I've been able to connect with many interesting people."

Comment: See related thread, [_"When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?"_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: Try "I met people I was able to connect with." for starters. Not sure what you mean by "reflection atmosphere", though.

Comment: What I mean is that I am writing a reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to write your first sentence, which I'm not sure that I would, which I'll get into in a moment, you would write it as follows:

> "During my daily work, I’ve met many interesting people whom I was able to
>   connect with."

You need a comma after the word *work*.  "During my daily work" is an introductory modifier.  As it adverbially modifies *have met* and precedes the subject, you would follow it with a comma.

You also need to say "whom" after the word *people*.  Why you may think you don't need to comes from the common mistake people make using *who* instead of *whom*.  The word *who* as a pronoun can work like the word *that*.  In English, when *that* is used as a pronoun in a restrictive clause, it can be implied, so omitted.  When *who* is used to mean *that*, it can likewise be omitted.  So, if you mistakenly think *who* is the right word for your sentence, you might think you can omit it.  But *who* isn't the right word because *who* can't function as an object, only *whom* can, as in, "I've met many interesting people with whom I can connect."  Not only is *whom* the object of the verb *connect*, but it's also the object of the preposition *with*.

The third problem with this is it's redundant.  If you were saying "connected with" in its sense that would mean you had created a deep interpersonal connection with those people you met, then it wouldn't be redundant.  However, based on your example, you're not saying this.  You're using *connected with* in a very cursory way, essentially saying, "I met people I was able to meet.

Your second option is much better but should appear as follows:

> During my daily work, I've been able to connect with many interesting
>   people.

In order to be grammatical, you would insert the necessary comma after the introductory modifier for the same reason explained before.

Answer (score -1):

correct usage goes here.

"During my daily work I meet many interesting people whom I am able to connect with"

Comment: Please explain why you made the changes you did and why the OP's sentence isn't also correct.

Comment: And also why your sentence *is* correct. (*Whom* is high-register usage, so one would expect the *with* to go with it as *...people with whom I am able to...*)