# How can I avoid a preposition at the end of a clause

Tags: prepositions

I want to say:

Thank you to all of you who have supported me and to whom I have had the pleasure to learn so much **from**.

Is the correct version:

Thank you to all of you who have supported me and from whom I have had the pleasure to learn so much.

Thank you.

Comment: Also consider: [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16/42471)

Comment: Thank you to all of you who have supported me. It has been a pleasure to learn so much from you all.

Comment: Why do you **want** to avoid it? There’s nothing wrong with prepositions at the end of clauses. Your original sentence is borderline ungrammatical, but not because of the _from_ at the end—it’s the jarring mismatch between “to all of you who” and “and to whom… from” that doesn’t work.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I did think it sounded incorrect. Perhaps its not the preposition that's wrong. Could you please advise alternate wording? Thanks

Comment: Just drop the repeated _to_: “Thank you to all of you who have supported me and who(m) I have had the pleasure to learn so much from”. Your own rewrite is perfectly fine as well. Stylistically, this does happen to be one of those cases where “from whom” is more elegant than “who(m)… from”; but you should think of it as selecting the more elegant option, rather than avoiding a particular construction just to avoid it, because in other cases, the stranded preposition will be more elegant.