# Is "What can I help with?" proper English?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> "What can I help with?"

Part of our team is claiming it is not proper english and another part is claiming its the correct way for us to say it.

For context this is in reference to working on a chat bot that will be helping customers so we are trying to keep it concise and at a simple level to be approachable to all users.

Comment: It's fine. Hot Licks is [trolling you](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/47/300). If the preposition is your concern to begin with. If it's something else, you will need to specify. Oh, and mate: "english" is the spin you put on the ball in billiards. Certainly you mean "English", the language. "May" is not the same as "may", "august" not the same as "August", and "March" a completely different thing from "march". Same with "English" vs "english".

Comment: I guess commenting on an English language stackexchange I should expect a diatribe about my capitalization :) Thank you, this was very helpful!