# something we were not notified of

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is this sentence correct?

> This is something we were not notified of.

Or is using *of* unnecessary in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands the sentence is OK. Omitting "of" is possible, but I doubt many native BrE speakers would do so.

There is a non-rule that a sentence should not end in a preposition, which has been debunked here on several posts [for example here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition?noredirect=1&lq=1), but if you were writing this formally you could say "*This is something of which we were not notified*"