# Prepositions with verbs in the end of sentences through 'and' or 'or'

Tags: prepositions

Can we use verbs and prepositions in the end of sentences through 'and' or 'or'? And if we can't, how should we rephrase it?

For example: I have someone to talk to and play with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a riff on the age-old question, "Can you end a sentence with a preposition?"

Essentially, you can grammatically end a relative clause with a preposition instead of putting it in the prescribed location. The sentence you have fits the underlying rules for comprehensible English.
The rule is archaic, and if followed, your phrase would need to be *I have someone to whom I can talk and with whom I can play*.

Gross.

I would argue your sentence is better, and highlights why the prescribed rule is archaic. That said, if you have an especially shallow Strunk & White adherent as an English teacher, they probably won't accept it.

Comment: Agreed! Saying it's "archaic" and a "rule" is being generous.