# Is this structure correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I wondered if the structure of these two sentences was correct :

```
1. And what self-narrative would this person engage in? 
2. In what narration?
```

The last sentence refers to the previous one.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you think is incorrect, what exactly you think would be correct instead, and why exactly you don't just use that instead. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt My hesitation comes from the use of the preposition "in" at the end of the first sentence. 
Regarding the second sentence, I was wondering if it were any other adjective than "what" to use instead.

Comment: "*My hesitation comes from the use of the preposition 'in' at the end of the first sentence.*" Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: I don’t think *engaging in a narrative* is quite right. What kind of story would he tell himself? Perhaps the awkwardness is an effort to avoid a gendered pronoun reference.