# with whom ... or whom with

Tags: prepositions, whom, who

In the sentence below:
"In user-based approach, the recommendation is based on users of the same neighborhood, **with** whom he/she shares common preferences."
why can't we say "In user-based approach, the recommendation is based on users of the same neighborhood, whom he/she shares common preferences **with**."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: The issue here is that the word '_whom_' is formal, whereas stranding the preposition at the end sentence instead of pied-piping it (_with whom_) is considered informal. So you have a mix of styles, which some may consider problematic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping