# Meaning of "on which to look back on"

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> New experiences can create new memories and reflections on which to look back on.

I find it difficult to understand and parse "on which to look back on". I am confused as to why there are two "on"s. What does it mean?

More examples can be obtained via googling "on which to look back on".

Comment: >*What does it mean?* It means that the speaker/writer has made a mistake. Only one of the "ons" is necessary.

Comment: @Greybeard Your comment implies it could be either one!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. :) I was hoping the OP would make the better choice, although the sentence as a whole is poorly constructed.

Comment: this is indeed difficult but thanks for asking it, something similar I had wanted to ask/ or also thought about. **ALSO** *@thatness Welcome to EnglishStackExchange!*

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition).

Comment: Greybeard is correct; only one "on" is needed. Either delete the last "on" or delete the initial "on which"

Comment: @Anton Even if you delete the last *on*, it's still wonky.

Comment: maybe something old-english can be used? (note I don't know what this could be but some times maybe a latin word?) Note I don't know at all *which is why the comment and not an answer.

Comment: You can either strand the preposition at the end or pied-pipe it along with the relative _which_, but you can't do both. Pied-piping will get you in trouble if you forget to delete the preposition at the end that you pied-piped to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer. This question is ungrammatical. It makes no sense. When the preposition is fronted, the clause of interest should have its preposition removed. It’s either a typo or written by someone that is unlearned.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many *on*s, but you can’t remove the last one; *look back on* is a phrasal prepositional verb — with a verb, an adverb particle, and a preposition. [The particle and the preposition cannot be separated.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs/#phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs__148)

These are incorrect:

> **New experiences can create new memories and reflections on which to look back.*
>
> **Working from home creates new challenges with which to put up.*

You’ll need to remove *on which*:

> *New experiences can create new memories and reflections to look back on.*
>
> *Working from home creates new challenges to put up with.*